# Update from Windows 1607 to 1809 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, dism

I was wondering if there are any relevant documentation explaining how we can do the windows update using dism powershell module.

I want to update from windows 1607 version to windows 1809.
Or is there any other way to do the update of windows using powershell apart from manual installation of windows 1809.

I tried using PSWindowsUpdate Powershell Module, but failed to do the windows feature update using this module. However could do the Windows cummulative update using the same.

I am very new to this area, but familiar with Powershell. Can anybody recommend the right path for me?

Comment: you can't do this. Mount 1809 or better 1903 ISO and run setup.exe to upgrade

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends a lot how you want to do it.
Do you want to update a local computer ? And directly 1607 to 1809 without going through all other version (1709 as exemple) ?

The easiest would be I think to make a dism and to install each "big update".

1. 1703
2. 1709
3. 1803

What do you use the computer for ? If you have some "special" application, it could be a good idea to do it for each version and test that everything works.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes i want to update a local computer. I might need to upgrade lot of computers and frequently. And i want to directly upgrade to the 1809/1903.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend downloading all big update (the all in one kind) for each version and creating a "bat" doing some DISM and adding each update one by one. It is the only way i see it could work.

Comment: feature updates and no normal updates, those are upgrades like Vista to Win7 or from Win7 to Windows 8. you need to run setup.exe from ISO and select upgrade